# Getting the mapping for a permutation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have two binary matrix where one is a permutation of the other:
How can I obtain the permutation mapping between both?

Example :

```
A=[1 0 1 0;1 1 0 0] 
B=[0 0 1 1;1 0 1 0]
```

`A->B` should be : `[3 1 4 2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use second output of the `ismember` function

```
[~, out]=ismember(A.',B.','rows')
```

Comment: Thanks @rahnema1 ! That's exactly what i was searching for.

Comment: @AKH Glad if I can help!